# Ada - Accessibility check raised within a procedure

Tags: ada, gnat, gnat-gps, ada2012

I previously asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60777489/230513) regarding accessibility checks being raised in Ada, which @Brian Drummond was kind enough to awnser. The accessibility check was in a function, now I have a similair problem within a procedure; any guidance as to why this is would be greatly appreciated.

The code I am working on has been taken from here: https://github.com/raph-amiard/ada-synth-lib

The code in main file below is from the the Simple_Sine example which can be found here: 
https://github.com/raph-amiard/ada-synth-lib/blob/master/examples/simple_sine.adb

My main file looks like this:

```
with Write_To_Stdout;
with Command; use Command;
with Effects; use Effects;
with Sound_Gen_Interfaces; use Sound_Gen_Interfaces;
with Utils; use Utils;

procedure main is
   pragma Suppress (Accessibility_Check);
   BPM   : Natural := 15;
   Notes : Notes_Array :=
     To_Seq_Notes ((C, G, F, G, C, G, F, A, C, G, F, G, C, G, F, G), 400, 4);

   function Simple_Synth
     (S    : access Simple_Sequencer; Tune : Integer := 0; Decay : Integer)
      return access Mixer
   is
     (Create_Mixer
        ((0 => (Create_Sine (Create_Pitch_Gen (Tune, S)), 0.5)),
         Env => Create_ADSR (5, 50, Decay, 0.5, S)));

   Volume     : Float   := 0.9;
   Decay      : Integer := 800;
   Seq        : access Simple_Sequencer;
   Sine_Gen   : access Mixer;
   Main       : constant access Mixer := Create_Mixer (No_Generators);
begin
   for I in -3 .. 1 loop
      Seq      := Create_Sequencer (16, BPM, 1, Notes);
      Sine_Gen := Simple_Synth (Seq, I * 12, Decay);
      Main.Add_Generator (Sine_Gen, Volume);
      BPM    := BPM * 2;
      Volume := Volume / 1.8;
      Decay  := Decay / 2;
   end loop;

   Write_To_Stdout (Main);
end main;
```

The error that's raised is this:
`raised PROGRAM_ERROR : sound_gen_interfaces.adb:20 accessibility check failed`

It is raised during a call to this procedure:

```
   -- Register_Note_Generator --
   -----------------------------

   procedure Register_Simulation_Listener
     (N : access I_Simulation_Listener'Class) is
   begin
      Simulation_Listeners (Simulation_Listeners_Nb) := N;
      Simulation_Listeners_Nb := Simulation_Listeners_Nb + 1;
   end Register_Simulation_Listener;
```

Which is line 20 of the code below:

```
with Ada.Containers.Vectors;

package body Sound_Gen_Interfaces is

   package PA_Vectors
   is new Ada.Containers.Vectors (Natural, Params_Scope);

   Params_Aggregators : PA_Vectors.Vector;

   function Current_FPA return Params_Scope is
     (Params_Aggregators.Last_Element);

   -----------------------------
   -- Register_Note_Generator --
   -----------------------------

   procedure Register_Simulation_Listener
     (N : access I_Simulation_Listener'Class) is
   begin
      Simulation_Listeners (Simulation_Listeners_Nb) := N;
      Simulation_Listeners_Nb := Simulation_Listeners_Nb + 1;
   end Register_Simulation_Listener;

   ---------------
   -- Next_Step --
   ---------------

   procedure Next_Steps is
   begin
      for I in 0 .. Simulation_Listeners_Nb - 1 loop
         Simulation_Listeners (I).Next_Step;
      end loop;
   end Next_Steps;

   ----------------
   -- Base_Reset --
   ----------------

   procedure Base_Reset (Self : in out Generator) is
   begin
      null;
   end Base_Reset;

   --------------------
   -- Reset_Not_Null --
   --------------------

   procedure Reset_Not_Null (Self : Generator_Access) is
   begin
      if Self /= null then
         Self.Reset;
      end if;
   end Reset_Not_Null;

   --------------------
   -- Reset_Not_Null --
   --------------------

   procedure Reset_Not_Null (Self : Note_Generator_Access) is
   begin
      if Self /= null then
         Self.Reset;
      end if;
   end Reset_Not_Null;

   --------------------------
   -- Compute_Fixed_Params --
   --------------------------

   procedure Compute_Params (Self : in out Generator) is

      procedure Internal (Self : in out Generator'Class);
      procedure Internal (Self : in out Generator'Class) is
      begin
         for C of Self.Children loop
            if C /= null then
               if C.Is_Param then
                  Add_To_Current (C);
               end if;
               Internal (C.all);
            end if;
         end loop;
      end Internal;

   begin
      Self.Parameters := new Params_Scope_Type;
      Enter (Self.Parameters);
      Internal (Self);
      Leave (Self.Parameters);
   end Compute_Params;

   -----------
   -- Enter --
   -----------

   procedure Enter (F : Params_Scope) is
   begin
      Params_Aggregators.Append (F);
   end Enter;

   -----------
   -- Leave --
   -----------

   procedure Leave (F : Params_Scope) is
   begin
      pragma Assert (F = Current_FPA);
      Params_Aggregators.Delete_Last;
   end Leave;

   --------------------
   -- Add_To_Current --
   --------------------

   procedure Add_To_Current (G : Generator_Access) is
      use Ada.Containers;
   begin
      if Params_Aggregators.Length > 0 then
         Current_FPA.Generators.Append (G);
      end if;
   end Add_To_Current;

   ------------------
   -- All_Children --
   ------------------

   function All_Children
     (Self : in out Generator) return Generator_Array
   is
      function All_Children_Internal
        (G : Generator_Access) return Generator_Array
      is
        (G.All_Children) with Inline_Always;

      function Is_Null (G : Generator_Access) return Boolean
      is (G /= null) with Inline_Always;

      function Cat_Arrays
      is new Generator_Arrays.Id_Flat_Map_Gen (All_Children_Internal);

      function Filter_Null is new Generator_Arrays.Filter_Gen (Is_Null);

      S : Generator'Class := Self;
      use Generator_Arrays;
   begin
      return Filter_Null (S.Children & Cat_Arrays (Filter_Null (S.Children)));
   end All_Children;

   ----------------
   -- Get_Params --
   ----------------

   function Get_Params
     (Self : in out Generator) return Generator_Arrays.Array_Type
   is
      use Generator_Arrays;

      function Internal
        (G : Generator_Access) return Generator_Arrays.Array_Type
      is
        (if G.Parameters /= null
         then Generator_Arrays.To_Array (G.Parameters.Generators)
         else Generator_Arrays.Empty_Array) with Inline_Always;

      function Cat_Arrays
      is new Generator_Arrays.Id_Flat_Map_Gen (Internal);

   begin
      return Internal (Self'Unrestricted_Access)
        & Cat_Arrays (Self.All_Children);
   end Get_Params;

   ----------------------
   -- Set_Scaled_Value --
   ----------------------

   procedure Set_Scaled_Value
     (Self : in out Generator'Class; I : Natural; Val : Scaled_Value_T)
   is
      V : Float :=
        (if Self.Get_Scale (I) = Exp
         then Exp8_Transfer (Float (Val)) else Float (Val));
      Max : constant Float := Self.Get_Max_Value (I);
      Min : constant Float := Self.Get_Min_Value (I);
   begin
      V := V * (Max - Min) + Min;
      Self.Set_Value (I, V);
   end Set_Scaled_Value;

end Sound_Gen_Interfaces;
```

Any help as to why this is happening would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: I'm guessing Main.AddGenerator calls the errant procedure? I still recommend putting together a minimal compilable testcase; for example there's a lot more than necessary in that package, and AddGenerator is missing.

Comment: Thank you @Brian that is a good shout! I will atempt this... Thank you

Comment: I can't give you an answer as to why (it could be a gnat bug or it could be legit, I don't know), but I can offer some workarounds depending on your needs.  I"m not sure if that is the type of help you are looking for.  It would require doing the listener a bit different though (for any of the workarounds).  Additionally if you have any special requirements (no heap, not limited, etc.) it would be good to know to focus the answer better.

Comment: Why do you change the name of the main program to `main` from `Simple_Sine`? GNAT (indeed, any Ada compiler) can take any library-level parameterless procedure as the main program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're seeing here is the result of (over-)using anonymous access types (discussed in [ARM 3.10.2](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-3-10-2.html), informally known as the “Heart of Darkness” amongst the maintainers of Ada).

I don't think there's a simple way around this (aside from using `-gnatp`, as we found earlier, to suppress all checks; though perhaps you might have luck with

```
pragma Suppress (Accessibility_Check);
```

in the units where there's a problem).

I managed to get a build without `Program_Error`s with a fairly brutal hack, changing the anonymous `access I_Simulation_Listener'Class` to the named `Simulation_Listener_Access` throughout and, for example,

```
function Create_Simple_Command
  (On_Period, Off_Period : Sample_Period;
   Note : Note_T) return access Simple_Command'Class
is
begin
   return N : constant access Simple_Command'Class
     := new Simple_Command'(Note       => Note,
                            Buffer     => <>,
                            On_Period  => On_Period,
                            Off_Period => Off_Period,
                            Current_P  => 0)
   do
      Register_Simulation_Listener (N);
   end return;
end Create_Simple_Command;
```

to

```
function Create_Simple_Command
  (On_Period, Off_Period : Sample_Period;
   Note : Note_T) return access Simple_Command'Class
is
   Command : constant Simulation_Listener_Access
     := new Simple_Command'(Note       => Note,
                            Buffer     => <>,
                            On_Period  => On_Period,
                            Off_Period => Off_Period,
                            Current_P  => 0);
begin
   Register_Simulation_Listener (Command);
   return Simple_Command (Command.all)'Access;
end Create_Simple_Command;
```

Ideally I'd have thought about having `Create_Simple_Command` returning a named access type too.

You can see where I got to at [Github](https://github.com/simonjwright/ada-synth-lib).

Comment: Thank you very much Simon for your detailed responce. I resorted to using -gnatp as I couldn't figure it out. Which I know is not ideal. I shall attempt your solution, once I have got my head around it, I'll shall write back. Thank you, Lloyd

Comment: This might run the risk of a memory leak if the listener array is stored in a non library level object or if there are operations to remove listeners (which is a common idiom for event listeners)?  Just asking for the general case.

Comment: @Jere the listener array is at library level; and there are no more (and no less) likely to be memory leaks with this version than with the original.

Comment: @SimonWright yep, I was asking in general to see the applicability of the solution in a general sense.  For the OP who is learning how to use access types, I figured it was important to highlight when/how this can be used incase they later make changes where it is no longer library level.